# Unable to Connect to the mlab Database from locahost

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to the mlab database from localhost using node.js. Here is my url `mongodb://username:password@ds151651.mlab.com:51651/learner;`(with correct user name and password). The application is throwing mongoerror: authentication failed. I tried same in https://glitch.com, with same code and url and It worked fine. Here is my COde.

```
 var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

app.listen(3000);
app.use('',function(req,res){
    MongoClient.connect(process.env.url, function(err,db){
        if(err){console.log("unable to connect to the database error: " + err);}
        else{
            console.log("connection established");

        db.createCollection("customers",function(err,res){
            if(err) throw err;
            else {console.log("db created");}
            db.close();
        })
    }

})
res.end("hello");
})
```

can you please tell what causing the error and how do i solve it.

Comment: Authentication error really only has one reason, and that is simply that the credentials you supply are actually not correct. Notably here you are using `process.env.url` which will basically mean that this environment variable is either actually not set at all or you typed something in incorrectly. There is no other cause. That's why we keep deleting the questions.

Comment: I copied the same env variable to glitch and it worked fine

Comment: I'll try to be clear one more time only. **IT CANNOT BE THE SAME**. There is no other reason for an authentication error other than you have provided **incorrect credentials**. If it were another problem it would be a different error. You do not have the same details. Check everything and correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, in local environment the `process.env.url` reading all the url including semi-colon resulting in wrong url. where as in glitch, somehow the `process.env.url` reading the url excluding semi-colon. So, as @Neil Lunn said the only reason to the authentication error is wrong url or wrong credentials.